# how to config webstorm Code Analysis ignore file

Tags: git, code-analysis

### [WebStorm] Performing Code Analysis ignore file settings

- When I use **git comit**, there also come out from **Code Analysis** for the **3rd js lib** warnings like **Comma expresion**!
  How do I **config** or some how **to ignore** those **3rd js lib file** from git Code Analysis?

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/7976758). Removed.

Answer (score 0):

In the project files panel, right click the directory that contains third party libraries (probably called `node_modules`, or `vendor`), then `Mark directory as` -> `Excluded`.

This will tell your IDE that that directory is not part of the project proper, and it won't be analysed anymore.